# Can I get the creator of an facebook event's profile pic, using FQL?

Tags: facebook-fql

I need to use the following fql to also get the creator's profile pic of an event. The creator column only returns their id, but i'm not sure if there's a way to do both of this nested queries.

SELECT eid, name, location, creator FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())

Answer (score 0):

First you make sure want you want to retrieve.
If you want the name and profile picture of the creator of an event you are in you can use below code:

```
SELECT name,pic_big FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT creator FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()))
```

But if you need event details also (as you already have that fql) you need to query two separate queries it cannot be done using nested queries